# Is "have been enjoying" correct in "Since they were very young, the children have been enjoying..." ?

Tags: tense, grammaticality, perfect-constructions

I am wondering whether the sentence below is right:

> Since they were very young, the children **have been enjoying** travelling by plane.

Have been enjoying is appropriate here? Or any other more suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using present perfect continuous: *Since they were very young, the children [have been enjoying] travelling by plane.* sounds to me like they have been flying in all the time that has passed. I would use present perfect simple: *...the children [have enjoyed] travelling by plane*.
The reason has less to do with [the difference between present perfect and present perfect continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Present_perfect) and more with *to enjoy* being a feeling, which have a tendency of not being used in the continuous tense, or when they are, they have a slightly different meaning (then they focus on a current state and not on a generally valid property).

PS: You should be *wondering*, not *wandering*, because the latter means walking around without a clear purpose.